# listening to multiple events with one listener?

Tags: php, events, symfony

I'm building an app in Symfony2 that has a social-driven aspect (many actions a user performs on the site will show up in a "news feed"-style list for others to view). I've determined that the sf2 event dispatcher/listener system is the best way to handle this, but I've run into something of a snag in trying to configure my listener to handle many different events.

The (now outdated) documentation I've found in my searches seems to indicate that at one point, event listeners could register on multiple events, but the code has been refactored, and now the configuration looks something like this:

`config.yml:`

```
services:
  social.listener:
    class: F\Q\C\N\SocialEventListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.listener, event: onSocialShare }
```

Is there any way to either:

1. Easily pass multiple events (something like `event: [onSocialShare, onSocialFriend, onSocialCreate]` works, but that feels like it will quickly get ugly and unmaintainable, clogging up my config file with potentially dozens of social events
2. Define the event to which I want to subscribe from code (as was done previously)
3. Or possibly another, better option that I haven't thought of yet

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Word back from the symfony-users google group (thread [here](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/176b3724ea1ee577)) is that the appropriate way to do this is by adding several tags:

```
services:
  social.listener:
    class: F\Q\C\N\SocialEventListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.listener, event: onSocialShare }
      - { name: kernel.listener, event: onSocialFriend }
      - { name: kernel.listener, event: ... etc }
```

So, it looks like currently, there is no good way of adding event subscriptions from listener code. Oh well.

Comment: But this is good for sharing state between each of those events in the same class so you can at least exit early from a given event if the conditions are not appropriate based on logic in other events.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be easier to use EventSubscriber,
you can define events you want to use directly in that class

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html